# Не попадает из одного message.handler в другой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть код который просит пользователя сначала указать имя, потом фамилию, но в handler обработки фамилии он не попадает

```
# Обработчик сообщения с именем
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text and message.text != '/register')
def handle_name(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if user_id in registered_users and 'name' not in registered_users[user_id]:
        registered_users[user_id]['name'] = message.text
        
        bot.reply_to(message, "Введите свою фамилию:")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Чтобы зарегистрироваться, используй команду /register.")

# Обработчик сообщения с фамилией
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text and message.text != '/register')
def handle_surname(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    if user_id in registered_users and 'surname' not in registered_users[user_id]:
        registered_users[user_id]['surname'] = message.text
        bot.reply_to(message, "Ты успешно зарегистрировался!")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Чтобы зарегистрироваться, используй команду /register.")
```

Когда пользователь вводит фамилию, выдаёт "Чтобы зарегистрироваться, используй команду /register." А должен писать что он успешно зарегистрировался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема в локальных и глобальных переменных. Фактически при записи в `registered_users` код записывает данные только в используемой функции, то есть *локально*. Чтобы избежать этого, используйте `global registered_users` в начале каждой функции.

Вообще использовать стандартные типы данных для записи данных не рекомендую. Рекомендую использовать БД, например SQLite3.

Также настоятельно рекомендую использовать `async def` вместо `def`.

Comment: Добавила global, все равно не работает

Comment: @NadezhdinaDarya `global registered_users` во всех функциях?

Comment: да, во всех функциях

Comment: Стойте, а как вы различаете, где обработчик имени, а где фамилии?